# Multiprocessing in Python for a short task that needs to run several times

Tags: python, parallel-processing, process, multiprocessing

EDIT : seems that I misused multiprocessing by starting a lot short processes instead of dividing it into n_cpu long processes

I'm doing multi processing optimization and it's the first time that I actually use this. I have a function that takes a short time to run, however it needs to run a lot of times. I tried this code :

```py
    processes = []
    # length is a variable that is in the order of 100k to 1M
    for j in range(0, length):
        p = mp.Process(target=mp_function)
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

However this takes a very long time to run and just freezes my computer. I've also tried this but it takes a very long time (I just decided to not let it finish as it clearly takes a lot longer than what is acceptable) :

```py
    processes = []
    for j in range(0, length):
        p = mp.Process(target=mp_function)
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since it's the same approach as indicated on [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) :

```py
   p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
   p.start()
   p.join()
```

From what I've read online, it seems that `Pool` is to be prefered when I have a few tasks that each takes a long time to execute, and `Process` is to be used when I have a lot of short tasks takes a short time to execute.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Can you also post mp_function please

Comment: `Process.join` waits for the process to terminate. You don't want that in the loop. A pool is likely a good choice here. How does each instance of `mp_function` know what to do differently than all of the others?

Comment: As far as I know each process is independant but uses the same functions

Comment: It's difficult to tell what the problem (and it's solution really is) without knowing your ``mp_function`` and it's input. You also say that your function runs in a "short time" (What does that mean? Nanoseconds, milliseconds, minutes...?). Then you say "this takes a very long time..." which indicates that you have some maximum execution time limit. (What's the upper time limit for your parallel execution?) Finally, when parallizing a task it matters what kind of task you want to parallize? (Please update your description so that there's enough context to understand what you're trying to do).

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to post the code, mp_function is just a function that sleeps for about the same amound of time than the code I'm supposed to optimize

Comment: (for some reason I could not edit the comment) Sorry for being unclear, but for now I'm still not too sure about some of it so I'll come back tomorrow with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pool may work well. It will take a value and return a result which involves some processing time, but if you keep it to simple types, its fairly fast. By default the pool will "chunk" the input data, meaning that it will send equal amount of work to each worker in chunks to reduce interprocess communication.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with mp.Pool() as pool: # using default 1 process per cpu, reduce
                            # if it makes machine run too slow
        result = pool.map(my_function, [None]*length)
```

That list could be large in your case, so an intermediate function that knows how to break things out may be reasonable.

```
def my_function_runner(num_calls):
    for _ in num_calls:
        my_function()

cpus = mp.cpu_count()
with mp.Pool(processes=cpus) as pool:
    num_calls_list = [length/cpus] * (cpus - 1)
    num_calls_list.append(length%cpus)
    result = pool.map(my_function_runner, num_calls_list)
```